# return multiple counts from single table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, case

I have a football fixtures table in the following format.

```
date date primary key
homescore int(4)
awayscore int(4)
```

Data is stored in the following format

```
DATE        |   HOMESCORE    |  AWAYSCORE
------------------------------------------
01-01-2014  |       1        |      0
08-01-2014  |       2        |      1
15-01-2014  |       1        |      1
22-01-2014  |       3        |      2
29-01-2014  |       0        |      0
06-02-2014  |       1        |      3
```

And so on...

I'd like to run a single query to return the won, lost and drawn totals.

```
select count(*) as won from fixtures where homescore > awayscore;
select count(*) as lostfrom fixtures where homescore < awayscore;
select count(*) as drawnfrom fixtures where homescore = awayscore;
```

The result of this single query would look something like...

```
Won      Lost      Drawn
3        1         2
```

Please can someone give me some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(homescore > awayscore) AS won,
   SUM(homescore < awayscore) AS lost,
   SUM(homescore = awayscore) AS tie
FROM ...
```

The boolean results of the `>`, `<` and `=` will get auto-converted to integer `0` or `1`, by mysql, which can then be summed up.

Comment: Brilliant answer and is just what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38644/1/0):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN homescore > awayscore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) WonCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN homescore < awayscore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) LostCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN homescore = awayscore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TieCount
FROM fixtures
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, and on the basis of these answers I've put together an SQL fiddle so you can try it for yourself.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/066ec2/1

It's a contrived example of "parents" and "children", but it demonstrates the act of getting "stats" for joined tables. Thanks for the answer Marc B!

Comment: If you would, please post the relevant portions in your answer as the other answers have. It helps people who find this answer later. Thanks